# django-haystack +solr spelling suggestion returns 'None'

Tags: python, django, search, solr, django-haystack

I'm using django 1.5.1 and solr 4.4.

I tried using Haystack Spelling API for suggestion in my django app. It's giving "`None`" as result for every wrong word. I tried haystack official docs and old question's suggestion from Stackoverflow but still no luck.

Here is the code attached which i'm using in my app:

`solrconfig.xml` config file: http://pastebin.com/mgqvHuS1

`schema.xml` file: http://pastebin.com/3ftxaMq8

And code for `search_indexes.py`, `job_text.txt` etc. is here: http://pastebin.com/fCNFWQ3b

Issue is that its giving `None` as spelling suggestion.

What's the reason? Any issue with `solrconfig` or `schema.xml` file? Why its not showing proper spelling suggestions?

Regards

Comment: Does "None" mean the value is a Python None or that it's hitting your "None Suggestion" branch because obj.suggestion is not populated?

Comment: The other thing which wasn't obvious is whether your view code is calling [sqs.spelling_suggestion()](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.0/searchqueryset_api.html#spelling-suggestion)